# Can static/dynamic linker cause LLVM global-object aliasing?

Tags: linker, llvm-ir

I'm working on code which analyses LLVM IR using LLVM's C++ API, and I'm trying to figure out when two or more [`llvm::GlobalObject`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html) values might end up naming the same piece of memory.  I need to never reach a false-negative conclusion.

AFAIK, [`llvm::Module::aliases()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a9e3907ac7bf356d10b0e2bce937cc190) enumerates the [module's explicit aliases](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aliases), which is a start.  My concern is that additional aliasing might be introduced later, in the following ways:

Consider this example:

```
@A = common global i32 0, align 4
@B = external global i32
@C = external dllimport global i32, align 4
...
```

I'm concerned that the static linker may have the freedom to bind `@A` and `@B` to the same piece of storage.  And/or that the dynamic linker might bind `@A` and `@C` to the same piece of storage.

Does anyone know if these are realistic possibilities?  And am I missing any other ways that post-compilation steps could cause two [`GlobalObject`'s](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html) to alias?

Comment: I guess a related simple question is this: If I have two global variables `@FOO = external global i32` and `@FOO = external global i32`, can I safely assume that even after the program is fully linked, `@FOO` and `@BAR` will name distinct pieces of memory.